# nginx app is not running on domain name, it runs with domain and port number

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, nginx

I have two separate apps running on my personal private virtual box(Linux centos). One app is in php running on Apache and another app is a flask app running on gunicorn and nginx. On my main domain(say phpapp.com) the php app is running. I wanted to run my flask app on another domain which is say(flaskapp.com). My flaskapp.com is a subdomain of phpapp.com

My php app is running on port 80 and flask is running on port 3200 (nginx, I changed the default). But when I go to flaskapp.com it doesn't show me my nginx app, but if I do flaskapp.com:3200 it shows the app. I don't want to use port 3200.

I read somewhere that I need to disable Apache and then run it but is there any alternative as I need that app to be running. Am I missing any detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly run two **different webservers** on the same IP and port, but you can run two **different applications in the same webserver**.

This means, that as long as you have one webapp in nginx and the other in Apache you can not directly have both available without a port spcifier.

If proxying is acceptable to you, you can set up a proxy in Apache (on port 80) to nginx (on port 3200) or the other way round.

Comment: i see, so just knowledge purpose by default domain is run on port 80 right?

Comment: Yes, the default port for HTTP is 80. For HTTPS it is 443.